# Romanization using bytes.translate

Tags: python, python-3.x

i write opensource project with url romanization ([WIKIPEDIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization)) and I want everyone to have everything worked correctly.

I want translate from more then one letters letter to another letter...

This basic is example: 
I want translate `чечевица` to `chechevica`, this is dict

```
{
    'ч': 'ch',
    'е': 'e',
    'в': 'v',
    'и': 'i',
    'ц': 'c',
    'а': 'a'
}
```

I can do it without `ч=>ch`, because using `maketrans` i can transmit only one letter

```
# Pytnon 3 
>>> print('чечевица'.translate(bytes.maketrans('евица', 'evica')))
чeчevica
```

How i can replcace one o more letters to one or more letters using `translate` in Python 3?

Yes, i know about iconv and etc., but all languages ​​have their own rules about writing and I want to follow their rules.

Thanks.

> Python docs
>
> 1. translate https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#bytearray.translate
> 2. maketrans https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#bytearray.maketrans
> 3. ord, chr https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html

Comment: You can't. That function only does one to one replacement.   You will have to use other methods.

Comment: @Max but i think, that if i will be use `re` or `str.replace` it maybe more slowly than `translate`... or not ?

Comment: Yes, but it will. If you want raw speed, do not use python. Translate replaces bytes with other bytes, one for one. It can be so fast because it already knows the size of the output string, the table is a fixed size, etc.